# short key bug in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My key bindings for copying line or down don't work from the shortcuts i.e.

CIRL + Alt + Up-arrow

CTRL + Alt + Down-arrow

not using any extension

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cuBZ.png)

Comment: You showed the keybindings for adding cursors above and below.  And they have different bindings??  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.